# How can I create a layout that spans multiple rows using Android TableLayout?

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

How would I go about creating the following layout using tablelayout? Column spanning is straightforward, but I haven't found any clear guidance on row spanning.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly, but will have to use nested layouts instead. In your case, using nested TableLayouts will be very inefficient though, so you should use a combination of other layouts.

Try something like:

```
LinearLayout with vertical orientation (1)
  LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation (2)
    Box like view + LinearLayout with vertical orientation (3)
                      Row 1
                      LinearLayout with horizontal orientation (4)
                        The Two Views
                      Row 3
  Your other large view
  Your other other large View
```

Here's a color coded version of your layout (each color is a new parent Layout)

[image]

Comment: Why inefficient? There's a way to do it by nesting TableLayout?

Comment: @Mattia TableLayouts themselves are nested LinearLayouts. By using the flow I described, you are nesting fewer layouts. So using a TableLayout nest for this will be less efficient than the multiple LinearLayout nest I've provided.

Comment: what is the "Box like view" element?

Comment: @Mattia Whatever your top right corner view is, which you've shaped like a box.